# Change 3D Tensor to get shape (BATCH_SIZE, SEQ_LEN, 1) in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, sequence, forecasting

I have a 26 months time series which I am using to train a forecasting `LSTM` model that forcasts for the next month after looking at past 12 months sequence. I have created the sequences and target but not able to get it in a shape that is required for LSTMs. I'll very much appreciate your help. Thanks a lot in advance. Below is my code:

```
print(df.loc[train_samples].values.shape) ### Prints: (6176, 26)

BUFFER_SIZE = len(train_nunique)
BATCH_SIZE = 64
SEQ_LEN = 12 

train_raw = (tf.data.Dataset
            .from_tensor_slices(df.loc[train_samples].values)
            .shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
            .batch(BATCH_SIZE))

def create_X_y(x):
    n = x.shape[1]-1
    
    past_sequence = []
    target = []
    
    for i in range(n):
        seq_idx = i+SEQ_LEN
        target_idx = seq_idx + 1
        
        if target_idx <= n:
            past_sequence.append(x[:,i:seq_idx])
            target.append(x[:,target_idx])
    
    past_sequence = tf.convert_to_tensor(past_sequence, dtype=tf.float32)
    target = tf.convert_to_tensor(target, dtype=tf.float32)
    
    return past_sequence, target

train_ds = train_raw.map(create_X_y, tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

### Test the X, y output
for ex_train_seq, ex_train_tar in train_ds.take(1):
    print(ex_train_seq.shape)  ### Print: (13, 64, 12)
    print()
    print(ex_train_tar.shape)  ### Prints: (13, 64)
```

My preprocessing step that generates sequences produces X and y shape of **(13, 64, 12)** and **(13, 64)** because it is sliding window over 26 months. How can get the **X** to `(64, 12, 1)` and **y** `(64,1)` which will be of the order (BATCH_SIZE, SEQ_LEN, 1) necessary for sequence modelling? If there is a better way structuring the data for forecasting please feel free to suggest. Thanks a lot in advance.